# Angular form validation how to output an error message

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I am testing this template driven form in angular.

```html
<form  name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">
  <input #cardInput type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="id_name"
         [(ngModel)]="pacient.name" maxlength="20" />
  <small class="form-text text-danger" id ="ref"[hidden]="!editForm.controls.name?.errors?.maxlength"
         jhiTranslate="entity.validation.maxlength" translateValues="{ max: 20 }">
    This field cannot be longer than 20 characters.
  </small>
</form>
```

I am testing if it outputs teh error message when it is not valid like this:

```html
 fit ('Blank input is not valid', async(() => {
               
                comp.paciente.tarjetaSanitaria = 'ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd' ;      
            

                }));
```

How can I make it that it outputs the error message when the input is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this by checking hidden attribute

```
errorMessage = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.text-danger'));
errorMessageElement = errorMessage.nativeElement;
expect(errorMessageElement.hasAttribute('hidden')).toEqual(false);
```

to test all error message you can use queryAll instead of query, queryAll return an array of DebugElements, it can be something like this

```
errorMessages = fixture.debugElement.queryAll (By.css('.text-danger'));
errorMessages.foreach(element => {
errorMessageElement = element.nativeElement;
 expect(errorMessageElement.hasAttribute('hidden')).toEqual(false);
})
```

Comment: And if a have plenty of text-danger classes and also hidden attributes in my code, which one does it controls? Is there a way to control all of them simultaneously, not only the first one for exmaple?

Comment: you can give them ids and test the one you want, something like this errorMessage = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#nameErrerMessage'));

Comment: to control all of them you can use queryAll instead of query, it will return and array of element, after that you can loop oven them and apply the same test

Comment: well that's another question :/

Comment: Right, I am accepting it and created a new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561674/expected-true-to-equal-false

Comment: It doesn´t work people, but it seems like a probable solution that can be combined with something else