# Expected true to equal false

Tags: javascript, html, angular, testing

I want to test something in angular that really is not in teh Anguar tutorial.

I am trying to test that when the value of this input is invalid teh error message is outputted, so the hidden atributte is false in the case of putting a wor with more than 20 haracters.

```html
  <input #cardInput type="text" class="form-control" name="tarjetaSanitaria" id="field_tarjetaSanitaria"
                 [(ngModel)]="paciente.tarjetaSanitaria" maxlength="20"/>
             <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.tarjetaSanitaria?.dirty && editForm.controls.tarjetaSanitaria?.invalid)">
                 <small class="form-text text-danger"  id="ref"
                    [hidden]="!editForm.controls.tarjetaSanitaria?.errors?.maxlength"  translateValues="{ max: 20 }">
                    This field cannot be longer than 20 characters.
                 </small>
```

My component has this:

```html
 paciente: Paciente = {tarjetaSanitaria: 'ddd'} as Paciente;
```

And my test:

```html
       fit ('Blank input is not valid', async(() => {
               
                comp.paciente.tarjetaSanitaria = 'ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd' ;
                spyOn(comp, 'save');
              var1 = comp.submitButton.nativeElement;
              var1.click();
              fixture.detectChanges();
              expect(comp.save).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#ref')).nativeElement.hasAttribute('hidden')).toEqual(false);

                }));
```

It always fails saying Expected true to qual false.IF I remove fixture.detectChanges it aways passes. Have I done something  wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? If I do this console.log(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#ref')).nativeElement.innerHTML); it prints the error messsage: The field....

Comment: Perhaps you need to check the value of the 'hidden' attribute instead of checking if the attribute exists?

Comment: To check you mean to print its value? It prints teh error message as I have commented above

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
 fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#ref')).nativeElement.hasAttribute('hidden')
```

reads as if it's testing if the `#ref` element has an attribute named `hidden`. If so, the result is unlikely to depend on the value of the attribute.

If the `nativeElement` property is an HTMLElement in the DOM which always has a 'hidden' attribute, you should be able to get its value using

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#ref')).nativeElement.getAttribute('hidden')
```

However I have no way of conveniently verifying the data type of the attribute. If it is a string you should expect its value to be the string "false". If it is a boolean you probably need to expect its value to be the boolean value `false`.

If you don't know the data type of the "hidden" attribute already, or how true and false are stored in the attribute, add some debugging code to establish the data type before proceeding further. Good luck!

Comment: Look, I printed the getAttribute hidden of my ref, so the line that you wrote an dit gives null